# Math Comp Question I wrote, counting distinct groups of shapes.

Tags: combinatorics

I don't know the answer, or if the solution is trivial. If anyone could help me that would be great.

> There are 60 distinct shapes, where each shape is put in groups of 5 where order does not matter. Every minute the groups are mixed such that each shape has 4 new distinct shapes. What is the least amount of time in minutes that it would take until new distinct groups could not be made.

Rewrite of question:

> There are 60 distinct balls, which are placed into 12 buckets with 5 balls in each buckets. Every minute, the balls are reshuffled again into 12 buckets of 5 balls such that each ball has never been in the same bucket as any of the balls currently in its bucket. How many minutes can elapse before such a reshuffling is impossible?

Comment: "Every minute the groups are mixed such that each shape has 4 new distinct shapes. ". What does that mean?

Comment: So they make new groups where each shape hasn't been in a group previously with those shapes.

Answer (score 0):

5 balls, means 4 balls not the exact ball in each bucket. As ${60\over 4}=15$, this is an upper bound on the number of fully distinct reshuffles possible, and hence the number of minutes.

Comment: There are ${60\choose2}=1770$ pairs, and each grouping uses up $12{5\choose2}=120$ pairs.  Since $15\cdot120=1800$, $15$ grouping are not possible.

Comment: I never said least upper bound ...

Comment: ... and I never said you did.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very difficult.  It's something like a [balanced incomplete block design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design), but it doesn't have all the symmetry.  Even for BIBD's, with all the symmetry, it is not known in general, which designs exist.

There are ${60\choose2}=1770$ pairs, and each grouping uses up $12{5\choose2}=120$ pairs. Since $15\cdot120=1800,$ at most $14$ groupings are possible.  This is just an upper bound though.  I'd be surprised if it were achievable.  I can't think of a way to find the least upper bound except by computation, and I imagine that might take a very long time.

If you want to keep the question, you might amend it to say something like, "Give the best bound you can on the number of minutes ...", but then grading becomes a bit judgmental.